# How to check if only one statement equals 0?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I got some trouble with finding the matching if-statement to check if only one entry equals 0 of 3. 
Here's the code:

```
def thanx(self):
    if len(self.e.get()) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter affordable infos")
        self.boo = False
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Submition done", "Thank you")
        self.boo = True
```

It is only checking if my variable `e` equals 0, but i actually got 2 more entries. I know i could check every single one individually, however there has to be an easier way of doing this.
Im using "tkinter" btw, but this shouldnt be too much important.

I tried it with `or` but this isn't working or I'm doing it wrong.
(Also tried to solve this with lambda, but again just errors...)

Maybe someone can help me there...

Edit:
I might have explained this a bit confusing, I'll add the rest of the code here that you can understand this better:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, W
from tkinter import messagebox

class MyForm:
    def thanx(self):
        if len(self.e.get()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter affordable infos")
            self.boo = False
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Submition done", "Thank you")
            self.boo = True
    def callback(self):
       #print("Name: %s\nPassword: %s\nEmail: %s" % (self.e.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))
       if self.boo:
            f = open("PrivatData.txt", "w+")
            f.write("Name: %s\nPassword: %s\nEmail: %s" % (self.e.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))
    def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.title("Your privat details")
            Label(self.root, text="Your Name").grid(row = 0, padx = 12, pady=5)
            Label(self.root, text="Password").grid(row=1, padx=12, pady=5)
            Label(self.root, text="Email").grid(row=2, padx=12, pady=5)
            self.e = Entry(self.root)
            self.e2 = Entry(self.root)
            self.e3= Entry(self.root)
            self.e.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2)
            self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
            self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
            self.e.focus_set()
            self.show= Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda:[self.thanx(),self.callback()])
            self.quit = Button(self.root,text="Quit", command = self.root.quit)
            self.show.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)
            self.quit.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky = W, pady=4)
            self.root.geometry("230x140")
            self.root.configure(background= "#65499c")
            self.root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= MyForm()
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand completely... Your variable `e` is a `list`? And you'd like to check whether one of its item is `0`, is that right?

Comment: So you mean can be 1 or 2 or 3, or only can have 1?

Comment: Noo, ive got 3 variables. e, e2, e3. And each of them is an entry where the user can enter his information. And my intention is to check if he filled in every information affordable, so that he wrote something in each line. And if he didnt fill in everything, it will remind him to add the missing information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
if any((len(self.e.get().strip())==0,len(self.e2.get().strip())==0,len(self.e2.get().strip())==0)):
    do stuff to say that user did not input all fields
else:
    do stuff to say that user inputted all fields
```

So full code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, W
from tkinter import messagebox

class MyForm:
    def thanx(self):
        if any((len(self.e.get().strip())==0,len(self.e2.get().strip())==0,len(self.e2.get().strip())==0)):
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter affordable infos")
            self.boo = False
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Submition done", "Thank you")
            self.boo = True
    def callback(self):
       #print("Name: %s\nPassword: %s\nEmail: %s" % (self.e.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))
       if self.boo:
            f = open("PrivatData.txt", "w+")
            f.write("Name: %s\nPassword: %s\nEmail: %s" % (self.e.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))
    def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.title("Your privat details")
            Label(self.root, text="Your Name").grid(row = 0, padx = 12, pady=5)
            Label(self.root, text="Password").grid(row=1, padx=12, pady=5)
            Label(self.root, text="Email").grid(row=2, padx=12, pady=5)
            self.e = Entry(self.root)
            self.e2 = Entry(self.root)
            self.e3= Entry(self.root)
            self.e.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2)
            self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
            self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
            self.e.focus_set()
            self.show= Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=lambda:[self.thanx(),self.callback()])
            self.quit = Button(self.root,text="Quit", command = self.root.quit)
            self.show.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)
            self.quit.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky = W, pady=4)
            self.root.geometry("230x140")
            self.root.configure(background= "#65499c")
            self.root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= MyForm()
```

Comment: This works too, thank you. But I dont know what strip does so the other answer sounds a bit clearer to me. Will check this out later, thanks!

Comment: @Dome271 `strip` removes the spaces in the beginning of the string and the end (`rstrip` for right side, and `lstrip` for left_, i do that for disallowing the spaces for inputs

Comment: @Dome271 Sorry spaces default, see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) to know more about this

Comment: @Dome271 Remove all `strip`s for allowing spaces

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that at the moment you are checking if some string element equals 0. 
For example

```
e = 'abc'
len(e) == 3 # True
l = []
len(l) == 0 # True
```

If you want to check if your string variable is 0 then simply:

```
if not self.e.get():
    messagebox.showerror("Error")
    self.boo = False
```

Comment: That does not make anything clearer. Do you want to check all those three elements? Then use a loop.

Comment: I updated my post with the entire code. Maybe its more understandable now. There are 3 entries where the user can add some information into. Now i want to check if the user fills in every entry and doesnt leave something empty. And if so, I'll throw him an error message

Comment: Currently I'm only checking for "e" if its not empty. This works fine. But how to check if any of the 3 entries contain nothing. Thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: I see now! Yes, yes, the accepted answer is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
if len(self.e.get()) == 0 or len(self.e2.get()) == 0 or len(self.e3.get()) == 0:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter affordable infos")
    self.boo = False
else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Submition done", "Thank you")
    self.boo = True
```

Since you have 3 variables, there's no way to check them all 'in batch' unless you build a data structure containing them and then check some conditions on that data structure. However, it does not give any advantage. If you add a new variable, say `e4`, you still have to add it manually to the the data structure.

Comment: Did you think about spaces

Comment: Yes thank you that was I was looking for. I probably explained it a bit confusing but  I'm not a native speaker. So sorry for that. Big thanks to you!

Comment: @Dome271 my pleasure :)

Comment: @U9-Forward sorry, what do you mean for spaces?

Comment: @Neb I mean if the user inputs like for example a space or a tab, that's still allowed

Comment: @U9-Forward you're right but the OP asked for how to check 3 variables in block. I don't know what they are supposed to contain or which element in them is a valid element

Comment: @Neb U9-Foward means that you need to ensure that the boxes don't just have whitespace in them (see my answer for more info)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that all three textboxes are not empty in one `if` statement, you can use the following:

```
if "" in [self.e.get().strip(), self.e2.get().strip(), self.e3.get().strip()]:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter affordable infos")
    self.boo = False
else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Submition done", "Thank you")
    self.boo = True
```

This is a short and neat way to write what you are trying to do. This works because `entry` widgets will return `""` if they are empty, and `self.e.get().strip()` makes the text returned empty (`.strip()` removes all whitespace at both the start and the end of the string) if it is just whitespace (`" "`, `\t`, `n`, etc...).

It is better to check the contents of the string rather than the length of it, because a box with just whitespace in it will **not** return 0, as shown below.

```
>>> len(" ")
1
>>> len("")
0
>>> len("\t")
1
```